how to get reflection on a surface while the surface has to be hidden from camera?

lower left is the footage/image where I want to put 3d object on it. upper left is my 3d setup where I use a plane for the desk ( image is projected on the plane to match camera angle). I use reflective material for the desk/table so I can get the reflection of the glass and sphere. upper right is the render result if I render all the objects . But I don't want to render the plane/desk , just need the sphere and glass + reflection on the table. I will comp them later on top of the desk image using compositing app.
So for the plane/desk , in the object property -> visiblity -> ray visbility -> turn OFF camera. The problem if I hide the plane this way, I will lost the reflection on that desk. How can I get reflection passes on the desk without rendering the desk object.
blend file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3rzWReivhvIXSjUOGR7qniCFqv2kuTx/view?usp=sharing
image link :
https://media.istockphoto.com/id/513821918/photo/close-up-of-a-luxurious-table-corner.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=wT5GL-dH1msU5DdieewhB_aahVTeiSgDgAbesxHdrMo=
Thanks
